# Numerical Optimization - tracking Floating point arithmetic round off error

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let's say I am working on to find the minimum of a function using quasi-newton method.

As in every iteration, there will be many function evaluations and as we are dealing with floating point numbers, there will be some round off errors as well(only considering the floating point arithmetic errors).

How can we track the round off error or basically the number of significant digits in our solution? I am interested in finding the most precise solution.

Comment: Not every rounding error in the iterations leading to a minimum argument will contribute to "the round off error" in the solution.  Your solution is really as good as the *final* iteration and its satisfaction of any convergence criteria.

Comment: @hardmath Isn't the tolerance used in the convergence criteria should depend upon the number of significant digits. Lets say I am using **|f(k+1) - f(k)|< eps** as my stopping criteria. Now what should be the minimum value of eps? If I took eps to be very very small, I will surely be in trouble due to round off errors.

Comment: The criterion $|f(x_{k+1}) - f(x_k)| \lt \epsilon$ might help us get a bound on how close $f(x_k)$ is to the *minimum value* of $f(x)$ without giving much idea how close $x_k$ is to the *argument* where the minimum is attained.  Yes, we should be concerned if our evaluation of the function $f(x)$ is not  precise enough to justify the comparison in such a stopping criterion.  Naturally advice on how accurate your function evaluation is depends on the implementation, and we'd prefer to use as much precision as practical in last few iterations.

Comment: @hardmath Sir, what should be the stopping criteria in case of quasi-newton methods? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not make your Question more specific?  Are the arguments $x_k$ vectors or scalars?  Is the function $f(x)$ smooth?  Convex?  Is it cheap to evaluate in double precision, or expensive to evaluate with something less precise?  Any context you can add will help Readers to provide better advice about stopping criteria and error bounds.

Comment: Related, at SciComp.SE: [Doubt regarding stopping criterion for Newton method](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/doubt-regarding-stopping-criterion-for-newton-method)

Comment: @hardmath I am trying to find the solution to convex multivariable problems. I am using ![||x_{k+1} - x_{k} ||_{2}/||x_{k}||_{2} < \varepsilon](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%7C%7Cx_%7Bk&plus;1%7D%20-%20x_%7Bk%7D%20%7C%7C_%7B2%7D/%7C%7Cx_%7Bk%7D%7C%7C_%7B2%7D%20%3C%20%5Cvarepsilon) as my stopping criteria. The problem which I am facing is if I decrease the value of **\varepsilon** below a particular value which varies for different functions, the program never converges. I want to know if there is any thumb rule to choose the value of eps.

Comment: ** || x(k+1) - x(k)|| / ||x(k)|| < eps