# Stopping test for optimization

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

In some problems, as it is difficult to satisfy the gradient tolerance, particularly if the gradient is computed only approximately and we generally opt for the step size tolerance. Since it is important to take the scale of the problem into account in this stopping test, I am using 
$$
  \frac{\| x(k+1) - x(k) \|}{\| x(k) \|} < \mathbf{eps}.
$$
as my stopping criteria. I am interested to know if this is a good way to stop in terms of stopping criteria or can it lead to unfavourable results. Also, How can one decide the value of **eps** or the minimum value **eps** can take?

Comment: Looks very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893650/27978

Comment: @copper.hat It was about the quantification of round off errors due to function evaluations(floating point arithmetic). There was no direct answer related to that. I am working on quasi newton implementations and want to know how should the value of **eps** be changed according to different convex functions. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why $\|x(k)\|$ is in the denominator. Presumably a good stopping rule would be (reasonably) translation invariant. What if $\| x(k) \| $ is large, then this could stop prematurely?

Comment: @copper.hat  But what if the values i.e x(k+1), x(k) are already very small, in this case dividing by x(k) helps to scale up the problem.

Comment: @copper.hat Also, what should be the bounds on eps value?

Comment: There is no general answer. It really depends on what you are trying to do. Stopping rules based on the gradient or cost decrease may be more appropriate. I really don't understand why the $\|x(k)\|$ is useful. Like I mentioned, translation invariant schemes seem better unless you know something relevant about the problem. From a practical perspective, a combination of rules is probably a better idea.

Comment: @copper.hat I searched on internet and mostly people prefer || grad(f(k+1)- grad(f()k))||< eps as the stopping criteria. lets say I used this for finding solution to function F(x). Now consider a new function G(x) = 10^10* F(x). For this function, solution should be same as that of F(x) but with the above criteria, the answer will be different; it fails to take into account the scale of the problem. Same goes for the cost decrease.

Comment: Creating an appropriate practical stopping rule is a non trivial task, not one that has an easy answer. It really depends on what you are trying to do. Practical schemes often involve multiple tests (number of iterations, cost decrease, change in iterates, etc.). Dividing by $\|x(k)\|$ is no panacea and drowns out poorly scaled components of $x(k)$ (in addition to making it harder to stop near the origin)

Comment: An ideal (no such thing :-)) criterion would be scale & translation invariant. I mean affine scaling of the iterates.

Comment: @copper.hat  Thank you for the advice :D. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Moreover, if your problem is convex and you have access to its dual problem, you can have a stopping criterion based on duality. It is often much more useful than other heuristic steps. Note that a dualcan be constructed for an unconstrained problem by adding dummy equality constraints.